# How to save custom objects to Parse cloud Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Right now I am trying to save a custom made object to the parse cloud. I am following this:

https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects

http://blog.parse.com/2013/05/30/parse-on-android-just-got-classier/

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.spicycurryman.hitup/com.spicycurryman.hitup.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for value: class com.spicycurryman.hitup.model.HitupEvent



  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for value: class com.spicycurryman.hitup.model.HitupEvent
            at com.parse.ParseObject.put(ParseObject.java:2746)
            at com.spicycurryman.hitup.MainActivity.addEvent(MainActivity.java:257)
            at com.spicycurryman.hitup.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:84)
```

I guess it was caused by the custom object class I created:

```
package com.spicycurryman.hitup.model;

/**
 * Created by Spicycurryman on 12/31/14.
 */

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HitupEvent {
    private String title, thumbnailUrl;
    private int year;
    private double rating;
    private ArrayList<String> genre;

    public HitupEvent() {
    }

    public HitupEvent(String name, String thumbnailUrl, int year, double rating,
                 ArrayList<String> genre) {
        this.title = name;
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
        this.year = year;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String name) {
        this.title = name;
    }

    public String getThumbnailUrl() {
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public double getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(double rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(ArrayList<String> genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

}
```

and I am storing the custom object like this:

```
   HitupEvent hitupEvent = new HitupEvent();




        hitupEvent.setTitle("Rohit "+ "wants to "+WhatEvent_String_main+ " at "+ WhereEvent_String_main +" on "+ WhenEventDate_String_main +" ,"+ WhenEventTime_String_main   );





        hitupEvent.setThumbnailUrl(roro_photo);

        hitupEvent.setGenre(singleAddress);


        hitupEventList.add(hitupEvent);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        ParseObject event = new ParseObject("event");
        event.put("newHitupEvent", hitupEvent);


        event.saveInBackground();
        event.pinInBackground();
```

What would be the proper way to store custom objects?

Comment: can you post your whole code properly

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use it this way you should make HitUpEvent subclass ParseObject ,

You can check out Parse documentation : https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#subclasses to learn more about this.

Subclassing ParseObject

> > To create a ParseObject subclass:
> >
> > Declare a subclass which extends ParseObject.  Add a @ParseClassName annotation. Its value should be the string you would pass into the
> >     ParseObject constructor, and makes all future class name references
> >     unnecessary.
>
> Ensure that your subclass has a public default (i.e. zero-argument)
>   constructor. You must not modify any ParseObject fields in this
>   constructor.
>
> CallParseObject.registerSubclass(YourClass.class) in your Application constructor before calling Parse.initialize().

Another option is to use a generic ParseObject and do something like this:

```
event.put("genre", "hip-hop");
event.put("title", "tigga");
```